# Bahaviour of SQL update using one-to-many join

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-update

Imagine I have two tables, **t1** and **t2**. **t1** has two fields, one containing unique values called **a** and another field called **value**. Table **t2** has a field that does *not* contain unique values called **b** and a field also called **value**.
Now, if I use the following update query (this is using MS Access btw):

```
UPDATE t1
INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.a=t2.b
SET t1.value=t2.value
```

If I have the following data

```
     t1                  t2
 a  | value          b  | value
------------        ------------
'm' |  0.0           'm'|  1.1
                     'm'|  0.2
```

and run the query what value ends up in t1.value? I ran some tests but couldn't find consistent behaviour, so I'm guessing it might just be undefined. Or this kind of update query is something that just shouldn't be done? There is a long boring story about why I've had to do it this way, but it's irrelevant to the technical nature of my enquiry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is known as a non deterministic query, it means exactly what you have found that you can run the query multiple times with no changes to the query or underlying data and get different results.

In practice what happens is the value will be updated with the last record encountered, so in your case it will be updated twice, but the first update will be overwritten by last. What you have absolutely no control over is in what order the SQL engine accesses the records, it will access them it whatever order it deems fit, this could be simply a clustered index scan from the begining, or it could use other indexes and access the clustered index in a different order. You have no way of knowing this. It is quite likely that running the update multiple times would yield the same result, because with no changes to the data the sql optimiser will use the same query plan. But again there is no guarantee, so you should not rely on a non determinstic query to get deterministic results.

---

**EDIT**

To update the value in T1 to the Maximum corresponding value in T2 you can use `DMax`:

```
UPDATE  T1
SET     Value = DMax("Value", "T2", "b=" & T1.a);
```

Comment: I thought so. Luckily, in my current instance it doesn't make any difference (all the multiple results from the linked table happen to contain the same value).
So, if I did want to create a deterministic version of this, I assume I need to JOIN to an aggregate query. I've tried the following:

    `UPDATE t1 
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT b, Max(value) AS MaxValue FROM t2 GROUP BY b
    ) AS t2m
    ON t1.a = t2.b SET t1.value = t2m.MaxValue;`


...but Access just complains about a syntax error in JOIN expressions and highlights the **t2** in the SELECT statement.

Comment: Oops, that SQL statement should be `UPDATE t1 INNER JOIN ( SELECT b, Max(value) AS MaxValue FROM t2 GROUP BY b ) AS t2m ON t1.a = t2m.b SET t1.value = t2m.MaxValue;`

I assume this is the correct thing to do?

Edit: That doesn't actually work. I just get a complaint from Access saying **Operation must use an updatable query.**
This is a problem I've had before. When using aggregate functions, this makes the the query non-updatable, even if you are just using that aggregation to update some values, exactly like I am trying to do. 
Is there a way around this?

Comment: That was exactly what I thought but couldn't get it to work. I've updated the answer with the correct solution to get the maximum value in T2 for each row in T1.

Comment: Cool. Just one more note though, the DMax criteria will require quotes as the a and b fields are characters. i.e. `UPDATE  T1
SET     Value = DMax("Value", "T2", "b='" & T1.a & "'");`

Answer (score 1):

When you execute the query as you’ve indicated, the “value” that ends up in “t1” for the row ‘m’ will be, effectively, random, due to the fact that “t2” has multiple rows for the identity value ‘m’.

Unless you specifically specify that you want the maximum (max function), minimum (min function) or some-other aggregate of the collection of rows with the identity ‘m’ the database has no ability to make a defined choice and as such returns whatever value it first comes across, hence the inconsistent behaviour.

Hope this helps.